# Nested Fragment issue - Parent fragment's is recreated when adding nested fragment dynamically

Tags: android

I am facing an issue while adding a nested fragment. It will cause to recreate it's parent fragment.

Scenario:

1. Have a parent activity.
2. It contain a fragment called ContainerFragment.java
3. ContainerFragment.java holds 2 child fragment.
4. One fragment is list of films.
5. When application started based on the user selection need to show the.description about it.
6. Based on the user selection dynamically adding FilmDetails fragments gives the pain.FilmDetails.java holds 2 child fragments. It will showed using view pager.

When I trying to add the NewsDetails fragment, it will cause to recreate the Container.java.

This will cause to looping issue.

Please suggest a way to solve this issue.

I am using android.app.Fragments.

Please suggest a good solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Because that's not normal behaviour, afaik

Comment: Hi Tobias Baumeister, I found the problem and solved it. In previous implementation, inside of nested fragment i was used NewInstance() method. After removing the function application working fine.